# Help with Magento and related products

Tags: magento

I have a customer product page that literally lives beside the catalog/product/view.phtml page.  It's basically identical to that page with a few small exceptions.  It's basically a 'product of the day' type page so I can't combine it with the regular product page since I have to fetch the data from the DB and perform a load to get the product information

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row['productid']);
```

To make a long story short, everything works (including all children html blocks) with the singular exception of the related products.

After the load I save the product into the registry with

```
Mage::register('product', $_product);
```

and then attempt to load the related products with:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/related.phtml')->toHtml();`
```

All of which give back the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in catalog/product/list/related.phtml on line 29`,
```

and line 29 is

```
<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>`.
```

Any help getting the relateds to load would be appreicated.

Comment: Just a quick FYI.  If you indent a line by four characters you'll get code formatting, and it's the preferred way of having code examples posted around these parts. That's why the edits.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.  That's what I get for doing it when I'm tired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't quite follow what you're trying to do, but I know why you're getting your errors.  You're creating a block whose class-alias/class is

```
catalog/product_view
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
```

but you're setting this block's template as

```
 catalog/product/list/related.phtml
```

The stock `catalog/product/list/related.phtml` template was built to be used with a `catalog/product_list_related` Block **only**, and not a `catalog/product_view` Block.

If you take a look at the class definition for a `catalog/product_list_related` Block  (which is a `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related`), you can see that there's a `getItems()` method.

```
public function getItems()
{
    return $this->_itemCollection;
}
```

which returns a collection.  The collection is set in the `_prepareData` method

```
protected function _prepareData()
{
    $product = Mage::registry('product');
    /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */

    $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
    ...
```

This collection is never set with a `catalog/product_view` Block, which is why you're getting your errors.

In your code above, if you switch to creating a `catalog/product_list_related` block, your errors should go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function relatedproductsAction(){

    $this->loadLayout();
    $relatedBlock = "";

    $rec_prod_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastAddedProductId(true);
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($rec_prod_id);
    Mage::register('product', $_product);


    $relatedBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_related')->setTemplate('catalog/product/related.phtml')->toHtml();

    echo $relatedBlock;
    exit;

}
```

Getting html of related block through ajax call, right after when product is added to cart. might be relatively helpful.